# Display gridview data on the basis of Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, gridview

I have a button click on which I want to display `gridview`

Earlier it used to display on the basis of `Datatable`

But now I want to display on the basis of `Array`

Here is the code

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = cmbEmp_Name.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
    var result = String.Join(",", selectedItems);

    string[] StrAreaInt = result.Split(new char[] { ',' });

    for (int i = 0; i < StrAreaInt.Length; i++)
    {
        Muster_Process(StrAreaInt[i]); // length comes here
        HiddenDiv.Visible = true;
        grdMonthlyProc.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem, other than repeatedly setting `grdMonthlyProc` and `HiddenDiv` to visible?  Is it not populating the gridview?

Comment: @fnostro: I have set them to visible `true` but no data is _populating_ in the gridview.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a list of selected Items from a DropDownList, is that correct?

Comment: @fnostro: yes u r right. also I want to show the selected Item data into the gridview, and that's not coming in the gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### .aspx Markup.

These are the controls I think you are using.

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cmbEmp_Name" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow"></asp:CheckBoxList>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:GridView ID="grdMonthlyProc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

#### Code Behind.

Make sure the DataSource is assigned only once, otherwise you will lose your selected items on each Postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    // Changes these to your field names
    cmbEmp_Name.DataTextField= "Name";
    cmbEmp_Name.DataValueField = "DoctorID";

    // This code populate the CheckBoxList in my own project
    // Your Post doesn't show how you populate your control
    // I assume it's being done elsewhere in your code.
    // But it is important to understand that if you do not load
    // the CheckBoxList within a `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` block anything
    // you select in the list will be lost when you click the button
    // because the control will be repopulated on Postback.

    cmbEmp_Name.DataSource = ef6Context.GetListOfNames().ToList();
    cmbEmp_Name.DataBind();      
  }
}

//Button1 Postback bind the Gridview.
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Once you select a number of items from `cmbEmp_Name` and hit your
  // button this statement will create and Array of `ListItem`s
  grdMonthlyProc.DataSource = cmbEmp_Name.Items
                                  .Cast<ListItem>()
                                  .Where(li => li.Selected)
                                  .ToArray();

  // And this will Bind the Array to the GridView.  Internally GridView 
  // will extract all Public Properties of a ListItem and automatically
  // generate a default set of Columns to display.  With a simple
  // redefinition you can display specific columns, but more on that later
  grdMonthlyProc.DataBind();

}
```

The Block of code in your post was doing too much work:

1. You were pulling all the Selected ListItems
2. THEN extracting the Value property
3. THEN Creating an array of `Value`
4. THEN using join to create a comma separated String of `Value`
5. ONLY to SPLIT it back into ANOTHER Array of `Value`

Then you have a for loop.  I don't know why, but you make calls to Muster_Process which I assume is relevant, but you don't say what it does. And you repeatedly set Visibility to the same controls (`HiddenDiv` and `grdMonthlyProc`) within the loop, which serves no purpose.  Once is enough outside the loop.

But on the very first line of your post you mention that you want to populate a GridView but you don't say what you wish to display.

Defined like this `grdMonthlyProc` will display all public properties of a ListItems:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdMonthlyProc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Redefined To this (note this change: `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` ) this will display ONLY the Value Property:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdMonthlyProc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value"  HeaderText="Value" />
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And adding an additional `BoundField` would display only the Value field and the Text Field:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdMonthlyProc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value"  HeaderText="Value" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text"  HeaderText="Text" />
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: your answer will make my requirement change. I just want to fill the gridview data on the basis of `selecteditems` in the array. kindly help me with that.. thanks :)

Comment: I'm not telling you to change anything.  Your post shows nothing but the Button Click event.  I have no idea how you obtain your data, how you populate your control, what control you're even using.  So I just posted some sample code I know works that pulls selected items from list control and populates a gridview via array.  You should be able to pick out the pieces you need.

Comment: See, I have a button click and multiple dropdownlist. So what I want is, after selecting items from the dropdownlist, I want its relevant data to be shown in the gridview after button click. Here is the html of the dropdownlist and button [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qagLrrjs/)

Comment: OK - can you edit your post to include the portion of the aspx page that generated that control?

Comment: I've modified my answer to use the controls I believe you to be using.  I'm going to add one more piece I think you need.

Comment: what all changes I need to make ? can u explain one by one. please

Comment: The above is a fully working example with a complete explanation on how to extract selected items from a CheckBoxList  and populate a GridView.  I don't know how to make this any more clear. But I'll try.

Comment: hi @fnostro thanks for the answer,  will check the above code and update you soon. Was busy with some other work.